# Text widget over image in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Is it possible to have a text widget over an image? In other words, I need to have a background image and be able to write text on that image (overlaid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to overlay an image with a text widget, and have the image be visible under the widget.

What you can do instead is use a `Canvas` widget, display the image in the canvas, and then create text items on the canvas. Text items on the canvas are editable, though you have to do a little work to set up some bindings.

There is a good explanation of how to create editable text items on a canvas here: http://effbot.org/zone/editing-canvas-text-items.htm

Comment: Do the text items on Canvas have the same features as the text widget?

Comment: @Demetris: that depends on exactly what you're asking. The text objects aren't text widgets, so they don't have features like marks and tags. Like the text widget, however, you can change the color, font, size, etc. See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_text-method for the list of attributes you can apply to a text object.