# Is it possible to have a red squiggly line appear under words in a Tkinter text widget without using canvas? (Like for misspelled words)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

As per the question title: Is it possible to have a red squiggly line appear under words in a Tkinter text widget without using a canvas widget? (The same squiggle as when you misspell a word)

I'm going for something like this:

[image]

If so where would I start?

Comment: Maybe you need canvas to do that,

Comment: Yeah, maybe... I was hoping to not have to use canvas. I was hoping there was some underline feature that I have not been made aware of yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Text widget over image in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491150/text-widget-over-image-in-tkinter)

Comment: @stovfl not really. I'm really hoping to not have to use a canvas. I'd rather create my own font lol

Comment: I think you would need to make your own fonts, can't see how else to do that. I don't think you would be able to have the color different then the font tho.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is just an example of using user-defined XBM as the `bgstipple` of part of the text inside a `Text` widget to simulate the squiggly line effect:

- create a XBM image, for example `squiggly.xbm`, like below:

[image]

A XBM with 10x20 pixels

- then you can config a tag in `Text` widget using the above XBM image file as `bgstipple` in red color:

```py
# config a tag with squiggly.xbm as bgstipple in red color
textbox.tag_config("squiggly", bgstipple="@squiggly.xbm", background='red')
```

- and apply the tag to the portion of text inside `Text` widget:

```py
textbox.insert("end", "hello", "squiggly") # add squiggly line
```

Below is a sample code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

textbox = tk.Text(root, width=30, height=10, font=('Courier New',12), spacing1=1)
textbox.pack()

# config a tag with squiggly.xbm as bgstipple in red color
textbox.tag_config("squiggly", bgstipple="@squiggly.xbm", background='red')
textbox.insert("end", "hello", "squiggly") # add squiggly line
textbox.insert("end", " world! ")
textbox.insert("end", "Python", "squiggly") # add squiggly line
textbox.insert("end", "\nthis is second line")

root.mainloop()
```

And the output:

[image][image]

*Note that the height of the XBM image need to match the font size and spacing between lines.*

Comment: ***the height of the XBM image need to match the font size ...***: What about non monospaced fonts?

Comment: Only the height of the font should be considered, so the font type does not matters.

Comment: Thanks, I see it's independent from the used font. The whole tagged area is taken into account and the *XBM* anchor seems to be `nw`.

Comment: Actually the XBM is used as a pattern to fill the whole tagged area.  You can see the effect if you use a bigger font size, for example 32.

Comment: This answer is the closest to what I was thinking of. Thanks!

Comment: @acw1668 Is there any way to have it update to match the font size?

Comment: @TRCK As I said at the end of my answer, you need to create the XBM image with a height to match the font size and spacing between lines.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks for the clarification. It is also important that you mark that this does not work for Macos. The bgstipple setting does nothing on macos

Answer (score 8):

I customized a frame,its layout(just an idea,it needs improvement):

[image]

When user input "Enter",it will generate a new entry and a new label(squiggly line widget).

If user type "Backspace" and this entry is null,it will delete both this entry and label(squiggly line widget).

When user type "Up" arrow,it will make previous entry widget focused.

....

Code:

```
import tkinter

class CustomText(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(CustomText,self).__init__()
        self.last_line = 0
        self.index_line = 0
        self.master = master
        self['background'] = 'white'
        self.check_func = self.master.register(self.check)

        first_line = tkinter.Entry(self,font=("",16),relief="flat",validate="key",validatecommand=(self.check_func,'%W','%P'))
        first_line.pack(fill="x")
        first_underline = tkinter.Label(self,background="white",fg="red",font=("",4))
        first_underline.pack(anchor="nw")
        self.widget_dict = {
            first_line:first_underline # a dict which save the squiggly line widget(as a value) and entry widget(as a key)
        }
        # bind event:
        first_line.bind("<Return>",self.create_new_line)
        first_line.bind("<Up>",self.to_previous_line)
        first_line.bind("<Down>",self.to_next_line)
        first_line.bind("<FocusIn>",self.focused)

    def focused(self,event): # when one entry widget is focused,change the index_line number
        self.index_line = list(self.widget_dict.keys()).index(event.widget)

    def create_new_line(self,event): # when user input enter,generate an entry and a label
        self.index_line += 1
        self.last_line += 1

        new_line = tkinter.Entry(self,font=("",14),relief="flat",validate="key",validatecommand=(self.check_func,'%W','%P'))
        new_line.pack(fill='x')
        new_underline = tkinter.Label(self, background="white", fg="red", font=("", 4))
        new_underline.pack(anchor="nw")

        # also bind an event
        new_line.bind("<Return>", self.create_new_line)
        new_line.bind("<Up>",self.to_previous_line)
        new_line.bind("<Down>",self.to_next_line)
        new_line.bind("<FocusIn>",self.focused)

        # the difference between the first line:when user delete all the words in this widget and he input "backspace" again, it will delete the entry and label widget,
        new_line.bind("<BackSpace>",self.delete_this_line)

        new_line.focus_set()
        self.widget_dict[new_line] = new_underline

    def to_next_line(self,event): # when user type "Down",go to the previous line
        if self.index_line != self.last_line:
            self.index_line += 1
            to_widget = tuple(self.widget_dict.keys())[self.index_line]
            to_widget.focus_set()
            if event: # to the same index of next entry widget.
                to_widget.icursor(event.widget.index("insert"))

    def to_previous_line(self,event): # when user type "Up",go to the previous line
        if self.index_line:
            self.index_line -= 1 # the number of index minus 1
            to_widget = tuple(self.widget_dict.keys())[self.index_line]
            to_widget.focus_set()
            if event: 
                to_widget.icursor(event.widget.index("insert"))

    def delete_this_line(self,event):
        if not event.widget.get():
            self.last_line -= 1
            self.widget_dict[event.widget].destroy() # delete it in visual
            del self.widget_dict[event.widget] # delete reference in the self.widget_dict
            event.widget.destroy()
            del event.widget
            self.to_previous_line(None)


    def check(self,widget_str,input_str): # this is an error-check function
        widget = self.nametowidget(widget_str) # convert the widgetname to a widget object

        # an example
        error_str = "abc"
        if input_str == error_str: # now is to check the grammar
            underline_widget = self.widget_dict[widget]
            underline_widget['text'] = "〜"*len(error_str)*2 # add a squiggly line visually
        return True

root = tkinter.Tk()
t = CustomText(root)
t.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Example image(show the squiggly line when user input "abc"):

[image]

---

What needs to be improved:

1. the line-height of label(squiggly line) should be smaller.(To make the squiggly line and entry widget closer)
2. Actually,the label(squiggly line) could be image.(In my example,one character == two "~" characters)
3. the function of checking.
4. you could add two scrollbars.