# How to do custom underlining in tkinter Text widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox, underline

I was making a text editor with tkinter, Python, when I saw the option to underline spelling mistakes or incorrect usage of words but after searching a little bit I found that for underlining the words there was only one type of underline present which was
a̲ s̲t̲r̲a̲i̲g̲h̲t̲ l̲i̲n̲e̲
but I couldn't find how to customize underlining into wavy or something else, like MS Word and others have.

[image: red wavy underline] [image: green grammar wavy underline]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I dont think we can get wavy underline.

Comment: May this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61604625/5317403) help.

Comment: Thanks @acw1668, now I have to figure out how to make *.xbm file. That's all. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think wiggled underline is available; however, as shown hereunder, you can set the color of the underline with the keyword option [`underlinefg`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/text.htm#M69):

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
txtw = tk.Text(root)
txtw.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

txtw.insert("1.0", 'abcd')

txtw.tag_add('ru', index1='1.1') #, index2='1.4') 
txtw.tag_config('ru', underline=True, underlinefg='red') 

root.mainloop()
```