# Double Underline text Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

please I need help using double underlines for a text in tkinter.
Sample code is:

```py
allbl=tk.Label(hmpage,text='Purchases', font='calibri 25 bold doubleunderline',fg='white',bg='#2a475e')
allbl.place(relx=0.45,rely=0.25,anchor="center")
```

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: Welcome! Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) add update your question accordingly.

Comment: There is not "doubleunderline" font property, so you cannot do it with a simple `Label`. With a `Text` widget I think you can adapt this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61604625/6415268) for double underline instead of the squiggly one it provides. Or you can use a `Canvas` to create text and draw two lines below.

Answer (score 1):

There is no font option for double underlining, therefore this cannot be done with a simple `Label` widget. However, one can create a custom class based on a `Canvas` to draw two lines below the text:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font

class DblUnderlineLabel(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        # collect text's properties
        font = Font(master, kw.pop('font', ''))
        text = kw.pop('text', '')
        if 'fg' in kw:
            fg = kw.pop('fg')
        else:
            fg = kw.pop('foreground', 'black')
        # initialize the canvas
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, master, **kw)
        # display the text
        self.create_text(2, 2, anchor='nw', font=font, text=text, fill=fg, tags='text')
        h = font.metrics('linespace')  # font property needed to position correctly the underlining
        bbox = self.bbox('text')   # get text bounding box in the canvas
        w = font.actual('size')//8 # scale thickness of the underlining with fontsize
        # create the double underlining 
        self.create_line(bbox[0], h - 1, bbox[2], h - 1, fill=fg, width=w, tags='line')
        self.create_line(bbox[0], h + int(1.1*w), bbox[2], h + int(1.1*w), fill=fg, width=w, tags='line')
        # resize the canvas to fit the text
        bbox = self.bbox('all')
        self.configure(width=bbox[2], height=bbox[3])

root = tk.Tk()
for size in [8, 16, 32, 64]:
    DblUnderlineLabel(root, text="Arial %i bold" % size, font="Arial %i bold" % size).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Text sample:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: @Belz you're welcome! There are few out of the box "fancy" features in tkinter but once you know thi slibrary well it is often possible to implement them yourself or find existing code online.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the font attribute incorrectly.

I would say...
Instead of writing this:

```
font='calibri 25 bold doubleunderline'
```

Write this:

```
font=('calibri', 25, 'bold underline')
```

Also I didn't write `doubleunderline` as nothing like that exists in tkinter so you would get a straight Traceback.

So the corrected code would be:

```
allbl=tk.Label(hmpage,text='Purchases', font=('calibri', 25, 'bold underline'),fg='white',bg='#2a475e')
allbl.place(relx=0.45,rely=0.25,anchor="center")
```

Comment: My pleasure. :)

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, I have to terms with the sad reality as at this time of writing that tkinter doesn't support the double-underline feature.